# How to Have a different Code for the First Time $.each() run?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When $.each() loop for the first time i have a different code but then my code will be same to end of the loop.

Comment: Please write an example cause it's really not understandable this way

Comment: Uhm ... that's the point of a loop? Use either a conditional or apply the function on the first element, and start a loop at the second element...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`each()` function have 2 parameters called `index` and `Element`
A function to execute for each matched element.

**You can try below code**

```
$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
  if(index == 0){
      // loop for the first time
  }
  else{
     // will run for all iteration but first 
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure it's 1 not 0 ?

Comment: Glad to help you .. please `accept` the answer it will helps other to find out correct answer ...